# Snowflake Data Model

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was playing around with Oracle SQL developer data modeler (SDDM) and created a data model with primary/foreign keys. When I convert it to get DDLs, I see the oracle syntax which is not going to work with Snowflake. So my question is, can you use Oracle SDDM to create data models for snowflake ?

Comment: Any example of not working code?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is almost certainly yes.  Snowflake is very forgiving in terms of syntax, and for example accepts the data type VARCHAR2.

You can even create tables with primary and foreign keys - although these will not be actually enforced by Snowflake.

You may find the following links helpful:

[CONNECTING TO SNOWFLAKE WITH ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER DATA MODELER (SDDM)](https://www.snowflake.com/resource/connecting-snowflake-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler-sddm/)

[HOW-TO: CUSTOMIZING ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER DATA MODELER (SDDM) TO SUPPORT SNOWFLAKE VARIANT](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Customizing-Oracle-SQL-Developer-Data-Modeler-SDDM-to-Support-Snowflake-Variant)

[How to configure Oracle SQL Developer data modeller on Snowflake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcreg5ZwMnI)